# What's the difference between single and double quotes in Perl?

Tags: perl, string

In Perl, what is the difference between `'` and `"` ?

For example, I have 2 variables like below:

```
$var1 = '\(';
$var2 = "\(";

$res1 = ($matchStr =~ m/$var1/);
$res2 = ($matchStr =~ m/$var2/);
```

The `$res2` statement complains that `Unmatched ( before HERE mark in regex m`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Double quotes use variable expansion.  Single quotes don't

In a double quoted string you need to escape certain characters to stop them being interpreted differently.  In a single quoted string you don't (except for a backslash if it is the final character in the string)

```
my $var1 = 'Hello';

my $var2 = "$var1";
my $var3 = '$var1';

print $var2;
print "\n";
print $var3;
print "\n";
```

This will output

```
Hello
$var1
```

Perl Monks has a pretty good explanation of this [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=401006)

Comment: You mean to say that in singe quote '\\(' consists of 1 character and in double quote "\\(" consists of 2 characters?

Comment: No, it's the opposite. '\\(' is 2 characters, and "\\(" is one.

Comment: The delimiter character must also be backslashed, and backslash in various other cases besides as the final character of the string (e.g. the two character string \' is '\\\'', not '\\'').

Comment: er... the print examples and their output is backwards.  print $var2 will print Hello, print $var3 will print $var1.

Comment: As Xetius mentions, you need to be careful escaping certain characters in interpolating quotes. One of the common misses is the '@' character: if you're stringifying email addresses, for example, be sure to escape the '@' if they'll be inside interpolating quotes.

Comment: Also, I say "interpolating quotes" because in Perl, ' and " aren't the only way to quote strings. q// and qq// are the equivalents of ' and ", respectively, and there are a slew of others: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

Comment: Why is everything about perl confusing af?

Comment: Another major difference is the availability of escape sequences. e.g. There's a reason you used `"\n"` and not `'\n'`.

Comment: Re "*Why is everything about perl confusing af?*", Single quotes allow simple literals. Double quotes allow complex literals. Useful. And not really confusing. And not unusual either: JavaScript, Python, C# and Bourne shell also have more than one kind of string literal. Single-quoted and double-quoted literals create values with different types in C, C++ and C#.

Answer (score 5):

' will not resolve variables and escapes

" will resolve variables, and escape characters.

If you want to store your \ character in the string in $var2, use "\\("

Answer (score 4):

Double quotation marks interpret, and single quotation do not

Comment: The idea is right, but you can't use 42isanumber as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Perl takes the single-quoted strings 'as is' and interpolates the double-quoted strings. Interpolate means, that it substitutes variables with variable values, and also understands escaped characters. So, your "\(" is interpreted as '(', and your regexp becomes m/(/, this is why Perl complains.

Comment: In single quotish strings it recognizes two escaped characters: the ending delimiter character and \.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to create regex strings you should really be using the [qr// quote-like operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

```
my $matchStr = "(";
my $var1 = qr/\(/;
my $res1 = ($matchStr =~ m/$var1/);
```

It creates a compiled regex that is much faster than just using a variable containing string.  It also will return a string if not used in a regex context, so you can say things like

```
print "$var1\n"; #prints (?-xism:\()
```

Answer (score 1):

"" Supports variable interpolation and escaping. so inside `"\("` `\` escapes (

Where as ' ' does not support either. So `'\('` is literally `\(`