# What is the difference between ' and " in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943795/difference-between-and) and I am wondering about the same thing in JavaScript.

If you use the character ' or the character " when making strings in JavaScript, the application seems to behave the same. So what is the difference between these two characters?

The only advantage I have seen in using ' to build strings is that I can do stuff like:

```
var toAppend = '<div id="myDiv1"></div>';
```

Instead of:

```
var toAppend = "<div id=\"myDiv1\"></div>";
```

Is there any significant difference between them that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

They are equivalent for all intents and purposes. If you want to use either one inside a string, it is a good idea to use the other one to create the string, as you noted. Other than that, it's all the same.

Answer (score 56):

Although not technically a difference in Javascript, its worth noting that single quoted strings are [not valid JSON](http://json.org), per se. I think that people automatically assume that since JSON is valid JS, that valid JS strings are also valid JSON, [which isn't necessarily true](http://jsonlint.com).

E.g.,  `{'key': 'Some "value"'}` is not valid JSON, whereas `{"key": "Some 'value'"}`  is.

Comment: Extremely nice point out

Answer (score 22):

There's no difference. The reason for its existence is exactly what you mentioned

Answer (score 6):

Good practice, according to Mozilla, is to use " " in HTML (where ' ' cannot be used) while reserving ' ' in Javascript (where both " " and ' ' can be use indifferently)...

Comment: Single quotes can be used in HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273354/are-single-quotes-allowed-in-html

Comment: Yes, according to the standard, but "some HTML clients (not necessary browsers) have compatibly issues on single quoting"... Therefore I suggest to follow Mozilla's guidelines.

Comment: Could you link to Mozilla since you're citing them? For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Single_quotes_vs._double_quotes

Answer (score 2):

I think there is another difference. If you do the following

```
var str1 = 'The \' character';
var str2 = 'The " character';
var str3 = "The ' character";
var str4 = "The \" character";
document.write(str1.replace("'", "%26"));
document.write(str2.replace('"', "%22"));
document.write(str3.replace("'", "%26"));
document.write(str4.replace('"', "%22"));
```

The document.write will fail for str1 and str4. That is the difference, but I don't know if there is a workaround to make them work.

Comment: In which browser do those document.writes fail?  I failed to get them to fail.  (Once I put enough closing brackets into that code)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log("mama+"mama"")

Output : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) 
after argument list
```

Now try:

```
console.log('mama+"mama"')

Output :  mama+"mama"
```

They are equivalent! but sometimes you want to use "" inside a string, and that why we have '

Answer (score 0):

As written above, there is no difference but for situation you need to use "/' inside a string.

I think a better practice for situation you need to concatenate strings with variables is using a template strings:
`Price: ${price}, Amount: ${amount}. Total: ${price*amount}`

That's way you can add " and ', and concatenate variables.

Much easier to read, much easier to write.

Answer (score -4):

WARNING!!!!

There is a difference. When adding to arrays, you have to use one or the other. The array gets confused when you use two different types of quotes.

Example:

```
//WILL NOT WORK
var array = ["apple","orange","banana"];

array.push('pear');

//WILL WORK
var array = ["apple","orange","banana"];

array.push("pear");
```

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail.  This does not match my experience, nor the testing I just did.