# What is the difference of operators " and ' in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am confused that what is the difference of operators " and  ' in javascript! 
like :
$('#check_fax_file')
$("#check_fax_file")
any suggestion?

Comment: It's not an operator, they are just quotationmarks.

Comment: There is no difference, and they are not operators.

Comment: It's a quotes. No differences

Comment: see [What is the difference between ' and " in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944081/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: The only reason there's two versions is because of JS's use in HTML. It's somewhat easier to write `<input onclick="alert('hi!')" />` than `<input onclick="alert(&quot;hi!&quot`)" />`.