# Why can't use document.getElementById to replace $ in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a newbie in JavaScript, I use a piece of code to convert JSON to HTML table.

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
function buildHtmlTable(myList,printSource,tablename) {
     var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);
     var title = document.getElementsByTagName("caption");
     title.innerHTML="<h>"+printSource+"</h>";
     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var row$ = $('<tr/>');
         for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
             var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

             if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

             row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
         }
         $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
     }
}

// Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
// Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
// all records
function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
     var columnSet = [];
     var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

     for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
         var rowHash = myList[i];
         for (var key in rowHash) {
             if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
                 columnSet.push(key);
                 headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
             }
         }
     }
     $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

     return columnSet;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body onload="buildHtmlTable(data_epgd, epgd);">
    <table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
        <caption>sn</caption>
    </table>
</body>
```

As you can see, there is a usage of `$("#excelDataTable")`. I thought it's just like `document.getElementById` function to find an element in HTML.So I use `document.getElementById` to replace it. But when I did this, the code didn't work any more.So can somebody explain what is the difference between `document.getElementById(excelDataTable)` and `$("#excelDataTable")`? And why I can't use `document.getElementById(excelDataTable)` as alternative?

Comment: `$('selector')` in jQuery returns a jQuery object while `getElementById('id')` returns an Element object (they are different objects that behave slightly differently)

Comment: `$` is more like `document.querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `$()` is actually more than just a selector, it also wraps it in a jQuery object. Later in your script your using jQuery functions like `.append`, and those don't work on vanilla objects. What you can do is select it regularly and when you need jQuery functions you wrap (`$()`) it again.

Furthermore a selector should be a string (`'element'`)  and not a variable (`element`), like Fred mentioned.

Comment: Does it matter to use `""` instead of `''`. I'm kinda confused about that, in most situation, do they both work fine？

Comment: `''` and `"""` are [equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/944092/3185307). It's best practice to just use one style throughout your codebase though. Also worth noting that if you're in a `json` file, only `""` is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your useful and detailed answer!

Comment: I noticed that  FredMaggiowski said $(document.getElementById()) is a bad expression, but if I want the string "#excelDataTable" in $("#excelDataTable") to be a variable, can I just use a variable replace the string, like $(variable)?

Comment: > a selector should be a string (`'element'`) and not a variable (`element`)

Your statement is not true. `document.getElementById('element')` can be rewritten as `var element = 'element'; document.getElementById(element)`. One should use a JavaScript String. Either a literal like `'string'` or a variable/function whose value/return value evaluates to JavaScript String

Comment: So if my variable represents a  string, it's ok to use $(variable)?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: OK, and why the string inside the bracket is "#excelDataTable" instead of "excelDataTable"?

Comment: Because the `#` stands for looking for an id, you can use any css query in `$()`

Comment: So using the version without `#` is incorrect, or they are both ok?

Comment: Using `$()` in jQuery is "equivalent" to using `document.querySelectorAll()`, with the notable difference that only the first one will allow you to use jQuery functions like `.append()`. Using it without the `#` would mean you'd look for a tag (like `<p>`) with the name `excelDataTable`

Answer (score 0):

The line below will return a jQuery object

```
$("#excelDataTable")
```

Meanwhile using

```
document.getElementById(excelDataTable)
```

will return you a DOMElement object, which obviously doesn't have jQuery methods.

jQuery accepts also a DOM element to be passed to the constructor. Thus eventually you could do so

```
$(document.getElementById(excelDataTable))
```

Comment: It should be `$(document.getElementById(excelDataTable))` or `$(document.getElementById("excelDataTable"))`?

Comment: The second one, `$(document.getElementById("excelDataTable"))`

Comment: Doing $(document.getElementById()) is the worst thing I've ever read. You're using jquery? Use it. You don't want to use jquery, use plain js. Don't use both

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and detailed answer!

Comment: @FredMaggiowski, we hear what we want to hear... I didn't say it makes sense to combine it into a single expression. It was just an example for the statement above that jQuery accepts DOM Elements as well. Thus in case  somewhy there is a DOM element object, you always can convert it to jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

`$()` is a shorthand for jQuery(). it is actually a function which  returns a collection of jquery compatible objects so that jquery functions can be used on these elements like append(),empty() etc.$() is  commonly used as a selector function in Jquery but it is more than a selector...

1. we can pass it a selector to get a collection of matching elements wrapped into collection of jquery objects from the DOM ..like `$('.btnClass'),$('#id'),$('table')`.
2. we can pass it a string of HTML to turn into a DOM element which you can then use it into the document.

   3.we can pass it a DOM element or elements that you want to wrap with the jQuery object.

   For more details refer documentation [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Core)