# Save CSV file with commas in a string

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

I'm creating a .csv file with nodejs `fw-extra`. I'd like to open this file using excel, however, I'm having problems where I have comma's in my string. I've been looking on stack overflow for a solution. The recommendation is to replace a`,` with `""`. When I do this, the `""` appear in excel. It doesn't seem to recognise this pattern. What am I missing?

The string I'm trying to save is `bob, 2`. In the example below I use the double quotes instead of a `,` as per the suggestions I've read.

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const name = 'bob"" 2';

async function loadUrl(page, url) {
  await fs.writeFile(
    "out.csv",
    "name\n"
  );
console.log(1);

  await fs.appendFile(
    "out.csv",
    `${name}\n`
  );
}

loadUrl();
```

Comment: In a CSV any field which contains a comma should be wrapped in "".  E.g. `A,"B,C",D`

Comment: Yes. When I do this and open it in excel the quotation marks are still there. Is this way it is supposed to work?

Comment: There are 3 fields there.  If I save that exact text in "tmp.csv" then open it in excel I get "A" in A1, "B,C" in B1 and "C" in C1 (without the actual quotes)

Answer (score 0):

i'll let this post talking about the difference between `'` and `"` in JavaScript, [what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944081/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript). With that being said, maybe your problem would reach a solution if you use `'` to create your strings except in the case where you have a double quote inside, in which case you should use `"`