# Perl::CGI Redirect with a Parameter and Access it in the New Page

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi

In PHP it is very common to redirect to a new URL and pass along information such as a 'username.'

```
<?php

   header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?user_name=$username' ) ;

?>
```

I can then access the value of 'user_name' in 'new_page.php.'

I can not figure out how to do this using perl.

```
print $cgi->redirect(-uri=>http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.pl?user_name=$username, -status=>303 , -cookie => $c );
```

I've tried using my `$username = $cgi->param('user_name')`, but it's not printing anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the quotes:

```
print $cgi->redirect(
         -uri=>"http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.pl?user_name=$username", 
         -status=>303,
         #... 
);
```

Also, remember escape the username before calling redirect:

```
my $username = escape( $cgi->param('user_name') );
```

Comment: The `escape` subroutine would need to be imported from somewhere, right?

Comment: Thanks, I don't use CGI much and didn't know it exported that subroutine.

Comment: I did forget the quotes in the example code but not in the actual code. It appears my problem was using single quotes. I just switched to double quotes and it appears to be working. I also got it to work with single quotes appending the $var with .  I can now access the value of user_name with  my $username = $cgi->param('user_name');  Thanks for the help.

Comment: In Perl, there are differences between single and double quotes. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943795/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-perl

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that PHP will work, but I'm not a PHP developer. If you gave the error it would help, but I think you need to quote the string.

```
print $cgi->redirect(
    -uri    => "http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.pl?user_name=$username",
    -status => 303,
    -cookie => $c,
);
```

You should add the following two lines (enabling the [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas) to the top of your script, they would have helped you debug the issue:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

For the record, I think the [PHP example should use double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple):

```
header( "Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?user_name=$username" );
```

Comment: I'm sure your right. I threw the php in there without checking syntax just so you would know what I'm referring to.