# In Perl what is the difference between double quotes("), single quotes(') and grave accent(`)

Tags: perl, operators

In Perl, what is the difference between quoting with double quotes("), single quotes('), and grave accents(`)?

This code:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use v5.10;
say "Hello";
say 'Hi';
say `Hola`;
```

gives the following result:

```
Hello
Hi
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html

Comment: I don't actually think this is very off-topic. It's a valid question, though it could have been researched by the OP. This stuff is very basic, but it's not easy to find if looking in perldoc directly.

Comment: @MattJacob In my case it was not 10 seconds of googling...

Comment: Let's not start a discussion here. There are currently two close votes on the question, both with the off-topic reason _request to find an off-site resource_. I didn't agree with those, so I voiced that disagreement. @MattJacob I think there was indeed. But the community decided to remove that (I'm not going to find a meta thread now). I still think it's a good question, though actually googling part of it finds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943795/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-perl, which is a near-duplicate. The backtick-angle is missing there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Single quotes `''`

Construct strings without [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). There is also a `q()` operator that does the same.

```
my $foo = 'bar';
print '$foo'; # prints the word $foo
print q($foo); # is equivalent
```

You would use single quotes when you just have text and there are no variables inside the text.

### Double quotes `""`

Construct strings with interpolation of variables. There is also a `qq()` operator that does the same.

```
my $foo = 'bar';
print "$foo"; # prints the word bar
print qq($foo); # is equivalent
```

Use these if you want to put variables into your string. A typical example would be in an old-fashioned CGI program, where you see this:

```
print "<td>$row[0]</td>";
```

The `qq()` variant comes in handy if your text contains double-quotes.

```
print qq{<a href="$url">$link_text</a>}; # I prefer qq{} to qq()
```

This is way easier to read than escape all the quotes.

```
print "<a href=\"$url\">$link_text</a>"; # this is hard to read
```

### Backticks ``` `` ```

Shell out and execute a command. The return value of the other program is returned. There is also a `qx()` operator that does the same. This interpolates variables.

```
print `ls`; # prints a directory listing of the working directory
my $res = qx(./foo --bar);
```

Use this if you want to write a script that is a bit more powerful than a shell script, where you need to call external programs and capture their output.

---

All the interpolating ones can only interpolate variables, not commands.

```
my $foo = 1;
my $bar = 2;
print "$foo + $bar";
```

This will print *1 + 2*. It will not actually calculate and print *3*.

---

All of those (and more) are explain in [perlop under *Quote and Quotelike operators*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: @choroba every time someone edits out one of my typos I get this warm fuzzy feeling that people actually read my stuff :D

Comment: Every time you typo on SO, you kill someone else's brain cell :-)